# Leitura de dados Firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react, native

Opa, tudo bem?

Estou fazendo um projeto da faculdade utilizando o *Firebase* e o *React Native*.

Desenvolvi uma tela onde eu quero publicar textos e mostrar para todos que estão utilizando a aplicação. Consegui salvar os dados no banco, porém não consigo mostrar ele na tela.

Essa é chamada para ler os dados do banco:

```
listarPub() {
    const publicadas = firebase.database().ref('Publicacoes').child('publicacao');
    publicadas.on('value', (snapshot) => {

   this.setState({ publicadas: snapshot.val()});
  });

}
```

Porém, não faço ideia de como faço para aplicar em um `Text` e/ou `FlatList` por exemplo.

Gostaria de saber se essa chama está correta e como faço para mostrar na tela. Tentei diversos tópicos, videos, etc, mas não consegui nada que me ajudasse.

OBS: É meu primeito post aqui, então não sei como me expressar direito é a minha primeira experiência com React e o Firebase.

Obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class ProductSpotLight extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            publicadas: null
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        if (!this.state.publicadas) {
            const publicadas = firebase.database().ref('Publicacoes').child('publicacao');
            publicadas.on('value', (snapshot) => {
                this.setState({ publicadas: snapshot.val() });
            })
        }
    }
    render() {
        const { publicadas } = this.state

        return (
            <View>
                {
                    publicadas &&
                    <Text>{publicadas.texto}</Text> //AQUI VAI CORRESPONDER AO VALOR DA PROPRIEDADE DO OBJETO QUE VOCE DESEJA MOSTRAR
                }
            </View >
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Oi Murilo. Então, fiz dessa forma e continua não retornado. Criei um console log: console.log(publicadas.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        this.setState({ publicadas: snapshot.val() }); e retorna como [Function anonymous]. Consegue me ajudar com isso?

Comment: consegue adicionar o log do erro da tela vermelha?

Comment: Ele não da erro, mas não retorna as publicações do banco. Há algo que eu possa fazer pra esclarecer melhor o motivo pra não retornar os dados?